What does isMutable : 0/1 mean?
I always see this on solana smart contract's Metadata &
I know for a fact that 0 means FALSE, and 1 is TRUE
as i've researched regarding this question, the owner can alter changes/settings if its set to 1 or TRUE
but which settings can the owner of the contract do?
can they mint more tokens? can they re-assign the ownership?
can they freeze someone's address/account? are there anything else to look for?
